# SQL - UPDATE within a SWITCH CASE

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, sql-update

I'm trying to run an update based on the value of a flag sent into a procedure but it does not like the syntax of the UPDATE statement here. What's wrong with it?

```
CREATE PROC [dbo].[TestProc]
    @ID int,
    @GET_COUNT bit
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT
        CASE 
           WHEN @GET_COUNT = 1  
             THEN (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM  [ORDERS]EMPLOYEE_ID = @ID)
           WHEN @GET_COUNT = 0  
             THEN UPDATE ORDERS SET EMPLOYEE_ID = null WHERE EMPLOYEE_ID = @ID
       END
GO
```

Comment: Use `IF-ELSE`. [`CASE`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx) is not control flow expression. *`The CASE expression cannot be used to control the flow of execution of Transact-SQL statements, statement blocks, user-defined functions, and stored procedures.`*

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? Please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Answer (score 3):

You are confusing a `SELECT . . . CASE` with `IF`.  Your code looks like T-SQL, so this is probably what you intend:

```
IF @GET_COUNT = 1
BEGIN
    SELECT COUNT(*) FROM  [ORDERS] EMPLOYEE_ID = @ID;
END;
ELSE IF @GET_COUNT = 0 
BEGIN
    UPDATE ORDERS SET EMPLOYEE_ID = null WHERE EMPLOYEE_ID = @ID
END;
```

Some SQL scripting languages do use `CASE` for control-flow as well as expression evaluations.  However, I think that `IF` is clearer in this context.